# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to deserialize a file, none of the other solutions are working for me.

This is the code. I get the error on the 'customerList' line

```
using (StreamReader customerStreamReader = 
                   new StreamReader(@"C:\...\ShoppingApplication\bin\Debug\Customer.xml"))
{
    customerList = (List<Customer>)customerSerializer.Deserialize(customerStreamReader);
}
```

Comment: Open Customer.xml in a hex editor and ensure the file starts with XML and has no extra characters like control characters or BOMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody coming here from google:

If you do not want to use XDocument, then you must make sure that your .xml is NOT empty. Once I added something, I was able to deserialize it just fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Look into using `XDocument` instead for it will be more robust in reporting errors, though the 0,0 location is a common one. Avoid using streams because they are so, .Net 2.

Here is an example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\...\ShoppingApplication\bin\Debug\Customer.xml");

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Then extract what is needed from the actual nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to use this instead.